# Docusign API: sign "here" or "there", one required, not both

Tags: docusignapi

I have a form that has two spots for a signature, chosen based on the signer's language. The signer needs to sign in one of those spots: it doesn't matter which, but one of them must be signed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to make both spots (tabs, signing elements, fields) be **optional**. That works since you must complete at least one signing element to finish/complete an envelope.
However, I think that's not a very clean solution as it will break if you want to add something like name/date etc.

A more robust solution would be using conditional fields.
I suggest you first try to do this from the web app, not using the API and understand the conditional fields functionality( https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields).

If you can have a radio button first selected, and then show the sign mark based on the selection - that's easy.